# why my review field of adminPanel always showing "N/A" even after i update the value of that field

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i was trying to make an app which have a sqflite db with a review field which is initilly have value Null...but when the admin update the value of the review field  the review controller.text must must be the updated value...and this will be saved to db...from that db when user log in the data in review field given by the admin must be visiable to the user....

**database code**

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sql;
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class SQL_DB_Helper {
  static Future<sql.Database> db() async {
    return sql.openDatabase('mydatabase.db', version: 1,
        onCreate: (sql.Database database, int version) async {
      await createTables(database);
    }, onOpen: (sql.Database database) async {
      await createTables(database);
    });
  }

  static Future<void> createTables(sql.Database database) async {
    await database.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myuserdb(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        names TEXT,
        emails TEXT,
        passwords TEXT,
        title TEXT,
        discription TEXT,
        members TEXT,
        year TEXT,
        project_link TEXT,
        review TEXT,
        createdAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
      )""");
  }

  static Future<int> addUserDetails(
      String username, String email, String password) async {
    final db = await SQL_DB_Helper.db();
    final data = {"names": username, "emails": email, "passwords": password};
    final id = await db.insert("myuserdb", data,
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
    return id;
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> userAlreadyFound(
      String uname, String e_mail) async {
    final db = await SQL_DB_Helper.db();
    final dataFound = await db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM myuserdb WHERE names = '$uname' OR emails = '$e_mail'");
    return dataFound;
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> checkLogin(
      String email, String pass) async {
    final db = await SQL_DB_Helper.db();
    final dataFound = await db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM myuserdb WHERE emails = '$email' AND passwords = '$pass'");
    return dataFound;
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getData() async {
    final db = await SQL_DB_Helper.db();
    return db.query('myuserdb', orderBy: 'id');
  }

  static Future uploadUserinfo(
      int id,
      String title_temp,
      String discrption_temp,
      String member_temp,
      String projectlink_temp) async {
    final db = await SQL_DB_Helper.db();
    final datas = {
      'title': title_temp,
      'discription': discrption_temp,
      'members': member_temp,
      'project_link': projectlink_temp
    };
    final dataUp =
        await db.update('myuserdb', datas, where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [id]);
    return dataUp;
  }

  static Future uploadUserinfoAdmin(
      int id,
      String title_temp,
      String discrption_temp,
      String member_temp,
      String projectlink_temp,
      String review_temp) async {
    final db = await SQL_DB_Helper.db();
    final datas = {
      'title': title_temp,
      'discription': discrption_temp,
      'members': member_temp,
      'project_link': projectlink_temp,
      'review': review_temp,
    };
    final dataUp =
        await db.update('myuserdb', datas, where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [id]);
    return dataUp;
  }

  static Future updateUserinfoAdmin(
      int id,
      String title_temp,
      String discrption_temp,
      String member_temp,
      String projectlink_temp,
      String review_temp) async {
    final db = await SQL_DB_Helper.db();
    final datas = {
      'title': title_temp,
      'discription': discrption_temp,
      'members': member_temp,
      'project_link': projectlink_temp,
      'review': review_temp,
    };
    final newdataUp =
        await db.update('myuserdb', datas, where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [id]);
    return newdataUp;
  }

  static Future updateUserinfo(
      int id,
      String title_temp,
      String discrption_temp,
      String member_temp,
      String projectlink_temp) async {
    final db = await SQL_DB_Helper.db();
    final datas = {
      'title': title_temp,
      'discription': discrption_temp,
      'members': member_temp,
      'project_link': projectlink_temp
    };
    final newdataUp =
        await db.update('myuserdb', datas, where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [id]);
    return newdataUp;
  }

  static Future deleteUserinfo(int id) async {
    final db = await SQL_DB_Helper.db();
    db.delete('myuserdb', where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  static Future updateDate(int id, String year_temp) async {
    final db = await SQL_DB_Helper.db();
    final datas = {'year': year_temp};
    final dataUp =
        await db.update('myuserdb', datas, where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  static Future getYearinfo(int id) async {
    final db = await SQL_DB_Helper.db();
    final result = await db.query('myuserdb', where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [id]);
    if (result.isNotEmpty) {
      return result.first['year'];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

**userPanel Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project_march/ui_ux_works/DataBase/sqflitee/signup_full/sqldbfunction.dart';

class userPanel extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? id;

  userPanel({required this.id});

  @override
  State<userPanel> createState() => _userPanelState();
}

class _userPanelState extends State<userPanel> {
  var formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var title_controller = TextEditingController();
  var discription_controller = TextEditingController();
  var member_controller = TextEditingController();

  var projectLink_controller = TextEditingController();
  var selectedYear = 2023;
  List userDataTemp = [];
  List userDataTemp2 = [];
  String reviewText = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    refreshUI();
  }

  void refreshUI() async {
    var catchData = await SQL_DB_Helper.getData();
    setState(() {
      userDataTemp = catchData;
      if (widget.id != null) {
        final existingData =
            userDataTemp.firstWhere((element) => element['id'] == widget.id);
        if (existingData['year'] != null) {
          selectedYear = int.tryParse(existingData['year']) ?? 0;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.id != null) {
      final existingData =
          userDataTemp.firstWhere((element) => element['id'] == widget.id);
      title_controller.text = existingData['title'] ?? '';
      discription_controller.text = existingData['discription'] ?? '';
      member_controller.text = existingData['members'] ?? '';

      projectLink_controller.text = existingData['project_link'] ?? '';
      final reviewText = existingData['review'] ?? 'N/A';
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(centerTitle: true, title: Text("USER PANEL")),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: title_controller,
                validator: (title) {
                  if (title!.isEmpty) {
                    return "title field must not be empty";
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "title",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: discription_controller,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                minLines: 5,
                maxLines: null,
                validator: (discription) {
                  if (discription!.isEmpty) {
                    return "discription field must not be empty";
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "discription about your project",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: member_controller,
                validator: (member) {
                  if (member!.isEmpty) {
                    return "Member field must not be empty.enter the members name";
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Members Name",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Year:'),
                subtitle: Text(selectedYear.toString()),
                onTap: () async {
                  final date = await showDatePicker(
                    context: context,
                    initialDate: DateTime(selectedYear),
                    firstDate: DateTime(2000),
                    lastDate: DateTime(2030),
                  );

                  if (date != null) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedYear = date.year;
                      updateYear(widget.id!, selectedYear.toString());
                    });
                  }
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: projectLink_controller,
                validator: (projectLink) {
                  if (projectLink!.isEmpty) {
                    return "Must provide GitHub Project link. field must not be empty";
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "GitHub Project link",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
              ),
              Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text('Review:',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                      Text(reviewText),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (widget.id == null) {
                      uploadDetails(widget.id!);
                    }
                    if (widget.id != null) {
                      updateDetails(widget.id!);
                    }
                    title_controller.text = "";
                    discription_controller.text = "";
                    member_controller.text = "";

                    projectLink_controller.text = "";
                  },
                  child: (widget.id == null)
                      ? Text("Upload Details")
                      : Text("Update Details")),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void updateYear(int id, String selectedYear) async {
    SQL_DB_Helper.updateDate(id, selectedYear);
  }

  void uploadDetails(int id) async {
    SQL_DB_Helper.uploadUserinfo(
      id,
      title_controller.text,
      discription_controller.text,
      member_controller.text,
      projectLink_controller.text,
    );
  }

  void updateDetails(int id) async {
    await SQL_DB_Helper.updateUserinfo(
      id,
      title_controller.text,
      discription_controller.text,
      member_controller.text,
      projectLink_controller.text,
    );
    refreshUI();
  }
}
```

**admin Panel code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project_march/ui_ux_works/DataBase/sqflitee/signup_full/sqldbfunction.dart';
import 'package:project_march/ui_ux_works/uiAss4.dart';

class adminPanel extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<adminPanel> createState() => _adminPanelState();
}

class _adminPanelState extends State<adminPanel> {
  List userDataTemp = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    refreshUI();
  }

  void refreshUI() async {
    var catchData = await SQL_DB_Helper.getData();
    setState(() {
      userDataTemp = catchData;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(centerTitle: true, title: Text("Admin panel")),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: userDataTemp.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final user = userDataTemp[index];
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(user['title']),
            subtitle: Text(user['members']),
            trailing: Text(user['createdAt']),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => UserDetailsPage(id: user['id']),
              ));
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UserDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;

  UserDetailsPage({required this.id});

  @override
  State<UserDetailsPage> createState() => _UserDetailsPageState();
}

class _UserDetailsPageState extends State<UserDetailsPage> {
  var selectedYear = DateTime.now().year;

  var title_controller = TextEditingController();
  var discription_controller = TextEditingController();
  var member_controller = TextEditingController();
  var review_controller = TextEditingController();
  var projectLink_controller = TextEditingController();
  var reviewTemp;
  Map<String, dynamic>? userData;
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    refreshUI();
  }

  void refreshUI() async {
    var catchData = await SQL_DB_Helper.getData();
    setState(() {
      userData = catchData.firstWhere((element) => element['id'] == widget.id);
      if (userData != null && userData!['year'] != null) {
        selectedYear = int.tryParse(userData!['year']) ?? 0;
        reviewTemp = userData!['review'];
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (userData == null) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      );
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
            onPressed: () async {
              showSheet(userData!['id']);
              refreshUI();
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () async {
              deleteDetails(userData!['id']);
              refreshUI();
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          Text('Title:', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Text(userData!['title']),
          SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          Text('Description:', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Text(userData!['discription']),
          SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          Text('Members:', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Text(userData!['members']),
          SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          Text('Year:', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Text(userData!['year']),
          SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          Text('Project Link:', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Text(userData!['project_link']),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Text(userData!['review'] ?? "Review : N/A"),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }

  void deleteDetails(int id) async {
    await SQL_DB_Helper.deleteUserinfo(id);
    refreshUI();
  }

  void showSheet(id) async {
    void uploadDetails(int id) async {
      SQL_DB_Helper.uploadUserinfoAdmin(
          id,
          title_controller.text,
          discription_controller.text,
          member_controller.text,
          projectLink_controller.text,
          review_controller.text);
      refreshUI();
    }

    void updateYear(int id, String selectedYear) async {
      SQL_DB_Helper.updateDate(id, selectedYear);
    }

    void updateDetails(int id) async {
      await SQL_DB_Helper.updateUserinfoAdmin(
          id,
          title_controller.text,
          discription_controller.text,
          member_controller.text,
          projectLink_controller.text,
          review_controller.text);
      refreshUI();
    }

    if (id != null) {
      title_controller.text = userData!["title"];
      discription_controller.text = userData!["discription"];
      member_controller.text = userData!["members"];

      projectLink_controller.text = userData!["project_link"];
      review_controller.text = userData!["review"] ?? "N/A";
    }
    showModalBottomSheet(
        isScrollControlled: true,
        elevation: 5,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => Container(
                child: Form(
              key: formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: title_controller,
                    validator: (title) {
                      if (title!.isEmpty) {
                        return "title field must not be empty";
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "title",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: discription_controller,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    minLines: 5,
                    maxLines: null,
                    validator: (discription) {
                      if (discription!.isEmpty) {
                        return "discription field must not be empty";
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "discription about your project",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: member_controller,
                    validator: (member) {
                      if (member!.isEmpty) {
                        return "Member field must not be empty.enter the members name";
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Members Name",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Year:'),
                    subtitle: Text(selectedYear.toString()),
                    onTap: () async {
                      final date = await showDatePicker(
                        context: context,
                        initialDate: DateTime(selectedYear),
                        firstDate: DateTime(2000),
                        lastDate: DateTime(2030),
                      );

                      if (date != null) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedYear = date.year;
                          updateYear(widget.id!, selectedYear.toString());
                        });
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: projectLink_controller,
                    validator: (projectLink) {
                      if (projectLink!.isEmpty) {
                        return "Must provide GitHub Project link. field must not be empty";
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "GitHub Project link",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: review_controller,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    minLines: 5,
                    maxLines: null,
                    validator: (review) {
                      if (review!.isEmpty) {
                        return "Review field must not be empty";
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Enter your review",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (widget.id == null) {
                          uploadDetails(widget.id!);
                        }
                        if (widget.id != null) {
                          updateDetails(widget.id!);
                        }
                        title_controller.text = "";
                        discription_controller.text = "";
                        member_controller.text = "";

                        projectLink_controller.text = "";
                        review_controller.text = "";
                      },
                      child: (widget.id == null)
                          ? Text("Upload Details")
                          : Text("Update Details")),
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```